# Wordpress won't recognize the MySQL database

Tags: arch-linux, php, mysql, wordpress

I want to install Wordpress on Archlinux but I have this error:

> Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.

I un-commented this line in `/etc/php/php.ini`:

```
; ... or under UNIX:
;
    extension=msql.so
;
```

but this error is not fixed. how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`msql.so` is not the PHP extension for MySQL.  Try enabling the correct module (`php_mysql`) and trying again.

Comment: what's correct module?

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, the correct module is `php_mysql`.